# Android 4.1.1/4.1.2 Date Picker Galaxy S3

Tags: javascript, android, html, input, modernizr

I'm using `<input type="date"/>` According to caniuse.com android browser does not support this yet. Although I look at the the page on the HTC One 4.1.x, which has its own native rendering for the input field. Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.2 has a rendering style for the component as well. Yet caniuse.com says its not supported. HTC and Samsung have clearly added this functionality into their version of android browser. The date picker on the S3 4.1.2 crashes the browser on more than one S3?

Steps to replicate, appears to be more common on first visit of the page:

1. Select the date picker move the month down twice.
2. Select set.
3. Page crashes/becomes unresponsive.

I'm using Modernizr, Modernizr tests the browser to see its functionality. On the HTCOne and S3 modernizr does not bring in the polyfill i'm using, this is correct.

So IOS works fine, Android does not. How can I get around this without a nasty hack in the modernizer "test:" Attribute?

Thanks, long one to read, but an interesting bug at best.

Mike

Comment: You only want it to work on those two devices? Unsupported is gonna give you trouble in the long run.

Comment: Hi Warpzit, we want a wide coverage on devices. We support a very large range of devices. Samsung galaxy has a high amount of traffic to the site so we needed to ensure it worked perfectly. We could have added a UA string check for a Samsung device, but in order to keep the detection method as simple and as clean as everywhere else we ended up using a polyfil for the time being which is for all devices. This will be until the visits to the site change and we'll review the date picker and retest the native picker on the latest versions of android on the Samsung s3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all Android systems are the same. Since everything is constantly getting updated, you're bound to get some small deviations like what you're getting. If you want more universal support, try using multiple selects or using the jQuery UI datepicker.